# GRE Tunnel for outbound traffic

Tags: networking

I using the GRE Tunnel on A Server and B Server
User connect to A Server, and how can i make A server return traffic by B Server through GRE Tunnel ?

Answer (score 0):

For systems behind the tunnel end point to receive replies you need to configure the routing table on the other side accordingly.